# clang-format for boost program options

Tags: c++, boost-program-options, clang-format

`clang-format` seems to make a big mess out of blocks like this:

```
desc.add_options()("help", "output usage")
      ("inputDirectory", po::value<boost::filesystem::path>()->required(), "The input path")
      ("outputDirectory", po::value<boost::filesystem::path>()->required(), "The output path");
```

I know about `// clang-format off` to explicitly not format a block, but is there a set of configuration rules to make it do something reasonable with this?

Comment: This isn't a solution, but when putting this code through [format.krzaq.cc/](http://format.krzaq.cc/), with the "file" style option, it's relatively unmangled. I don't know what exactly "file" means but might be worth checking with that page's author.

Comment: FYI I've [asked the author of `format.krzaq.cc` on GitHub](https://github.com/KrzaQ/cppformat/commit/a5e65d88f287993a938c1b35f769ed4f203caefb#commitcomment-20277562) - there's no `.clang_format` file in the repo, but they might have an almost-suitable file in the installation on their website.

Comment: It seems that `ColumnLimit: 100` does the trick. Not sure if it's an answer for you.

Comment: @krzaq Not really - that only works because we kind of got lucky here. If you change the limit to 150, it breaks very strangely.

Comment: I think you're out of luck here.  The program options are chained with () as operator - this way clang format's this like it would format function calls. Maybe you should ask yourself "is this be best/cleanest way to write down my intention?". Consider using a separate variable for the input-/outputDirectory part. auto&& outUsage = desc.add_options()("help", "output usage"); outUsage("inputDirectory", ...

Comment: I've opened https://github.com/llvm/llvm-project/issues/62658

Answer (score 4):

Not sure if you can handle it by only configuring `.clang-format` options. However, there is still something that you can do about `boost::program_options` syntax. Instead of chaining `operator()` you could create `program_options::options_description` object and add options in multiple lines:

```
namespace po = boost::program_options;

po::options_description desc;
desc.add_options()("inputDirectory", po::value<boost::filesystem::path>()->required(), "The input path");
```

Now even if clang-format breaks your formatting, I believe this will look a bit better than before. If it is not good enough for you and formatting is your pain in the neck, I'd suggest defining some function or whatever to shorten these lines (in our project we've got vector of ConfigField structures that contain value_semantic, names etc. and we iterate it calling add_options - it looks shorter).

No other way I'm afraid.

BTW: Yea, it's kinda old question, but there's no answer and we had similar problem recently.

Comment: You could improve the answer by adding one more line in the `desc.add_options()` example. The reader will see your intention quicker. Please provide an example with your vector solution.

Answer (score 4):

clang-format cannot remove comments, so adding comments at the end of lines enables nice looking code while maintaining the benefits of automatic indentation. This is especially helpful with items from libraries like boost::assign. For example when using ColumnLimit of 100 in clang-format:

```
    group2 = boost::assign::list_of<score_pair>("Norway", list_of(1)(0))("USA", list_of(0)(0))(
        "Andorra", list_of(1)(1));

    // Versus:

    group2 = boost::assign::list_of<score_pair> //
        ("Norway", list_of(1)(0))               //
        ("USA", list_of(0)(0))                  //
        ("Andorra", list_of(1)(1));
```

Using the desc.add_options example from above, adding line-break comments looks like:

```
    desc.add_options()("help", "output usage")                                                 //
        ("inputDirectory", po::value<boost::filesystem::path>()->required(), "The input path") //
        ("outputDirectory", po::value<boost::filesystem::path>()->required(), "The output path");
```

Answer (score 0):

Some stupid checker may also report that "You shouldn't put `(` before whitespaces". So you may define temporary local variable to store `options_description_easy_init`.

```cpp
auto op = desc.add_options();
op("help", "output usage");
op("inputDirectory", po::value<boost::filesystem::path>()->required(), "The input path");
op("outputDirectory", po::value<boost::filesystem::path>()->required(), "The output path");
```

And then use `clang-format` to reformat the code.